# Does this type of polymorphism has special name? (One class implementing two or more interfaces)

Tags: java, polymorphism

Just for learn:

Say we have:

```
interface Musician { /* content skipped */ }
interface Teacher { /* content skipped */ }
interface Swimmer { /* content skipped */ }

class Crack
 implements Musician, Teacher, Swimmer {
   /* implementation skipped */
}

Crack me = new Crack ();
```

So we have that Crack objects are "polifacetic" (many faces).
Is this term generally understood? Any other term for a class
implementing more than one interface?

Recall that polymorphism does not imply this. Instead you usually have
many classes deriving from *one* same base class or interface.

Comment: google "polifacetic class".. 288 hits. i guess it isn't generally understood ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would saw that Crack objects are multifaceted.

Comment: "multifaceted" does appear in the dicionary !
(Not like "polifacetic", with very few hits in google, @stmax points)

Comment: Unfortunately, the hits in google for "multifaceted class" have nothing to do with programming :-(